# UITabBar will hide the last cell of the UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbar

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height ) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

[image]

If I change the tableview frame to

```
(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height -49.0)
```

[image]

the scroll bar will leave a blank,I do not like it.How can I fix this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tab bar covers UITableView's last cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463157/tab-bar-covers-uitableviews-last-cell)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could try setting the `contentInset` of that table view. In iOS 7 there's a `topLayoutGuide` and `bottomLayoutGuide` (which is what you want). Inside of a `UITabBarController` the `bottomLayoutGuide` should give you the height of the bottom bar basically.

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0);
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks,tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 49, 0) works!

Comment: You probably want to avoid using any magic numbers here still. Especially when you support device rotation for instance. bottomLayoutGuide will always reflect the current height of your UITabBar.

Comment: Yes sir, you are right.Now I'm using "self.bottomLayoutGuide.length".

Comment: My self.bottomLayoutGuide.length when I log it returns 0. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: @jaytrixz It's probably 0 because layout has not occurred yet. Try updating the contentInset in your controller's viewDidLayoutSubviews method.

Answer (score 29):

Set the translucent property to `NO`

```
// In init or viewDidLoad of tab bar controller
self.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

Now the tab bar should resize the table view.

The `translucent` property is available iOS 7 and up.

Comment: so frustrating to see so many people suggesting setting the opaque tab bar to translucent. do u not understand the problem the OP is asking?

Comment: `self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false` for swift 4

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 options:

**First**

```
self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0
```

*This will do the trick and save the **transparent** property of the `tab` bar.*

---

**Second**
In design view just uncheck the option `Under Bottom Bars`, But put in your mind the `tab bar` will look like solid color (no thing behind it).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wanted to use heightForFooterInSection and return tabbar height , but "Under bottom bars" is better solution if u have tabbar with many tableviews.

Answer (score 1):

// In viewDidLoad() the following lines worked for me

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
 self.tabBarController?.tabBar.translucent = false`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift**:

```
self.tabBar.isTranslucent = false
```

<sub>Note: @Eric Amorde answers converted to Swift.</sub>