# UITableView last cell hidden by UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am facing a strange issue.

I have a `UITableView` in the initial `UIViewController` of the `UITabBarController`. At first everything is alright, but when I change the tab and come back to first tab the last cell of `UITableView` is hidden by the tabbar.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "last cell of tableview is hidden by the tab bar"? Does it appear behind it? If so, can you please attach a screenshot and post relevant code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tab bar covers UITableView's last cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463157/tab-bar-covers-uitableviews-last-cell)

Comment: Yes it appears behind tabbar, I havent done anything in code, Its just managed by the storyboard.

Comment: @NitinGohel in the link there are workarounds like adding a blank footer or adding subview, I am looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

select your specific `ViewController` from storyboard then un-check Under Bottom Bar property.