# Last cell is cut off at the bottom with my UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have one main `viewController` A with an `UITabBar`. My issue are when I scroll to the last cell and after I go to the `viewController` B with a cell click in `UITableView` and when I come back to my `viewController` A, my last cell is cut off at the bottom and I can scroll for appear all content of this cell. But by default at the bottom the `UITableView` doesn't keep the same place that last time.

When I launch `viewController` B I hide my `UITabBar` with this code in VCB "`viewWillAppear`" :

```
- (void)hideTabBar {

    UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    UIView *parent = tabBar.superview;
    UIView *content = [parent.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    UIView *window = parent.superview;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect tabFrame = tabBar.frame;
                         tabFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(window.bounds);
                         tabBar.frame = tabFrame;
                         content.frame = window.bounds;
                     }];
}
```

And when I come back to my `viewController` A I show my `UITabBar` with this code in VCB "`viewWillDisappear`":

```
- (void)showTabBar {

    UITabBar *tabBar = self._tab;
    UIView *parent = tabBar.superview; 
    UIView *content = [parent.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    UIView *window = parent.superview;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect tabFrame = tabBar.frame;
                         tabFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(window.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(tabBar.frame);
                         tabBar.frame = tabFrame;

                         CGRect contentFrame = content.frame;
                         contentFrame.size.height -= tabFrame.size.height;
                     }];
}
```

I have the same problem in iOS 6 but the scroll doesn't allow to go at the bottom and the last cell are cut off always.

In my `viewController` A in "`viewWillAppear`" I do:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion hasPrefix:@"7"]) {
    [self._tabBarControllerArticle.tabBar setTranslucent:NO];    
}
```

- Before when I clicked (image 1)
- When I come back (image 2)

[image: Before when I clicked]

[image: When I come back]

Thanks for advance for all the answer!!!

Comment: Check this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296065/ios-tabbarviewcontroller-hide-the-tab-bar

Comment: That doesn't works, after that I don't show my tabBar

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing it is to set translucent property of the `tabBar` to `NO` like this

```
// In init or viewDidLoad of tab bar controller
self.tabBar.translucent = NO;
```

Assuming you're using iOS7 this should adjust your `UITableView` just above `self.tabBar`

Comment: Thank's but isn't my question

Answer (score 1):

Click your tableViewController where the problem is happening, go to the Attributes Inspector, scroll down and uncheck the "Under Bottom Bars" box.

[image]

The selected answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994765/uitableview-last-cell-hidden-by-uitabbarcontroller) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to assign frame back to your view. See the updated code.

```
- (void)showTabBar {

    UITabBar *tabBar = self._tab;
    UIView *parent = tabBar.superview; 
    UIView *content = [parent.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    UIView *window = parent.superview;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         CGRect tabFrame = tabBar.frame;
                         tabFrame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(window.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(tabBar.frame);
                         tabBar.frame = tabFrame;

                         CGRect contentFrame = content.frame;
                         contentFrame.size.height -= tabFrame.size.height;

                         //YOU MISSED TO ADD BELOW LINE....
                         content.frame = contentFrame;
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks but with this lines I have a black bar just above my UITabBar, but apparently the cell are good but just behind black bar... Just on IOS 7 and in IOS 6 I have the same behavior that earlier for IOS 7

Comment: How can I remove this black bar without to hide my UITabBar ? @Apurv