# Last cell of UITableView is hidden by Tab Bar on iPhone 4

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I have a simple `UITableView` with custom cells. I've tested it on iPhone 5 and it worked fine, but unfortunately it doesn't works properly on iPhone 4. The last `UITableViewCell` is hidden by the tab bar. If I drag up the cells with my finger I can see the last cell, but it will be hidden again since I stop dragging the table view.

I've found some related questions with answers, but non of them solved the problem. I've unchecked the "under bottom bars" option in Interface Builder, and tried this (from an SO answer):

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, self.bottomLayoutGuide.length, 0);
```

I'm not sure what causes this issue, because the tab bar hides the table view content only on the iPhone 4, maybe it's an auto layout problem, but I don't think so, because I tried to fix it with constraints (without any success).

I would appreciate any tips or suggestions, that can help me out.

Comment: working with AutoLayout?

Comment: Use AutoLayout and set constrains. If not use it then tell me I will help you out in other way.

Comment: @AmiriDev I'm using autolayout, and tried with constraints

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView last cell hidden by UITabBarController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994765/uitableview-last-cell-hidden-by-uitabbarcontroller)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```