# TabBar hopelessly covering my ContainerView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5, uitabbarcontroller

I have a custom UIContainerView. Inside the UIContainerView is a Controller with a  UITableView. The TabBar keeps covering the last cell of my TableView. How do I prevent that from happening? I already tried the suggestions at [TableView Showing Behind Tab Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884381/tableview-showing-behind-tab-bar)  and [Tab Bar covers TableView cells in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325677/tab-bar-covers-tableview-cells-in-ios7?rq=1) and [Tab bar covers UITableView's last cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463157/tab-bar-covers-uitableviews-last-cell?rq=1) at all levels: in the VC holding my container view and in the VC of the TableView, as appropriate. I am not having much success. I set the constraints, I remove constraints — still nothing. Help!

I am using iOS7 and Xcode5.

Comment: Showing some code would be helpful, as well as a screenshot.